# HtmlUnit (junit) me is returning an error in the code

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, htmlunit

first anything clarified that I am using Google Translator. I am Hispanic. not be much English

Well, said you what I need to do

I'm trying to make this code work but it gives me an error, note that I am putting as same ta at the official website::
official website: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html

```
package serieflv;
import org.junit.Test;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import junit.framework.Assert;
       public class webClient {
            @Test
            public void homePage() throws Exception {
                final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
                    final HtmlPage page =    webClient.getPage("http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net");
                    Assert.assertEquals("HtmlUnit - Welcome to HtmlUnit", page.getTitleText());

                    final String pageAsXml = page.asXml();
                    Assert.assertTrue(pageAsXml.contains("<body class=\"composite\">"));

                    final String pageAsText = page.asText();
                    Assert.assertTrue(pageAsText.contains("Support for the HTTP and HTTPS protocols"));
                }
            }
        }
```

These are the errors that I launches
[These are the errors that I launches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjEDd.png)

Comment: Are you using version 2.19 of HtmlUnit?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have to have incorrectly imported a JUnit 3 class here while your test case is clearly a JUnit 4 test case.

Have the following line

```
import junit.framework.Assert;
```

modified to

```
import org.junit.Assert;
```